# How to know if XMLHttpRequest has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, xmlhttprequest, photo

I'm uploading multiple files with form field

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" multiple
```

a loop sends all files to upload function

```
       // Upload photo function
            var upload = function (photo, callback) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('photo', photo);
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState === 4) {
                        callback(request.response);
                    }
                }
                request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
                request.responseType = 'json';
                request.send(formData);
            };  


    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        upload(resizedFile, function (response) { });
    }
```

if all files are successfully uploaded, want to redirect ..

```
//all files finished, go to ...
if(response !== null && typeof response !== 'object') var response = JSON.parse(response);
window.location.href = "my-new-url.php?id="+response.id;
```

my problem, the redirect is done before all uploads are finished. how can I make the script wait for all xmlhttprequests to finish?

---

### EDIT

I changed the upload function like this, to upload with jQuery. The fuction is called several times from the for loop, so how can I wait for all loops/jquery calls are finished, then redirect?

```
function upload (photo, callback) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('photo',photo);

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){

            },
        });
    };
```

Comment: Create a promise for each request, and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can increment a global counter variable in the callback. When it reaches the length of the array, all the requests have completed.

```
var completed = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    upload(resizedFile, function (response) {
        if (++completed == files.length) {
            window.location = redirect_url;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would *promisify* the upload function. With JQuery would be much shorter as `$.ajax` returns a thenable object, but with old-fashioned vanilla JS, it would look like this:

```
var upload = function (photo) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                resolve(request.response);
            } else {
                reject(request.statusText);
            }
        };      
        request.onerror = function() { reject(request.statusText) }
        request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
        request.responseType = 'json';

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('photo', photo);
        request.send(formData);
    })
}
```

See also: http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/promisify/

Then I would collect these promises in an array:

```
var uploads = files.map(function(file) { return upload(resizeFile(file)); })
```

(or simply iterate as you did and push them in an array)

Then you can use this code to handle the completion of all uploads:

```
Promise.all(uploads)
   .then(function(results) { /* do the redirect */ })
   .catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

**Note:** Why is counting suggested in an other answer wrong? Because it does not handle the condition when any of the requests fails. You will not be able to detect that case, and you will never reach the condition to be satisfied. Promises (and async/await) are the right way of handling asynchronous operations, like ajax requests.

**[Update]**

Here is the JQuery approach using the latest JS language features:

```
var upload = (photo) => {
   photo = resizeFile(photo);

   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('photo', photo);
   return $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'upload.php',
     data: formData
   }) // check other the options of ajax method, you might need them
}

let uploads = files.map(upload);

$.when.apply($,uploads)
  .done(_ => { /* do the redirect */ })
  .fail(e => { /* handle error */ })
```

The latter part can be written with `async/await` syntax:

```
async somefunction(){ 

  // rest of the code

  try {
     await $.when.apply($,uploads)
     /* do the redirect */
  } catch(ex) {
     /* handle error */
  }
}
```

Note, that `$.ajax` returns [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), which is a JQuery object, compatible with Promise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation .. how would it look like with jQuery ajax? Would it be shorter/simpler then promises?

Comment: Please see my EDIT above at question .. I'm changed the upload function to jquery .. but how can I check within the for loop if all uploads has finished .. then redirect ?!

Comment: @Aldee please read my whole update carefully. The method I have posted returns a `Deferred` (like a `Promise`). I have mapped all uploads into an array. That means I have an array of Deffered-s. Now the last part with `$.when` combines all of them in a single Deferred, which completes of fails. On the other hand, you could easily upload multiple files in a single request.